# MySql logic on user permission

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, user-controls, user-permissions

Alright I'm having a dilemma right now

Im developing a web app that have mutiple users with their own data displayed when they logged in.

Example:

User1 logged in and created 4 different sets of data which will be data1 to data4

User1 obviously can view all of his data but couldn't manage it well so he asked some users to do the job. user2 to manage his data2, user3 to data3 and user4 to data4 but those users also have their own data that they can only and can hire others to do the job for them.

You can see it as a facebook page where you can add people as moderators

Im thinking of user table and another table that contains sets of data

When the user logged in ill use the username as key to view the list of data under that user but should I do it for the helpers if they have their own data?

Like if user2 logged in, user2 will be able to see his data and user1's data but user1 couldn't see his data

Answer (score 0):

You're quite far solving this riddle. What I would do is completely separate the users from the permissions. In its simplest form it would look like this:

```
User table
user1 name1 email1 password1
user2 name2 email2 password2
user3 name3 email3 password3
....

Permission table
Permission1 data1
Permission2 data2
Permission3 data3
....
```

Now you make a third table that will link any user to any permission:

```
Privileges table
user2 permission2 owner
user1 permission3 guest
user5 permission5 owner
user2 permission3 guest
....
```

This makes it easy to query who has permission to what.

Of course you need to extent this schema a lot. Also think about any other demands you might have (in the future) on the system, because this might not be the correct schema for that.

Comment: What if its a thousand user and user1 can grant permission to user2 user3 user4....  UserN

Comment: @Mark: Can you explain what 'problem' you see? I don't understand. Just to be clear: I've only been talking about the database schema, not the user interface.